# Как добавить колонку в таблицу MySQL Через SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

У меня есть таблица нужно добавить в нее длинную таблицу с int, подскажите как это можно сделать в интернете только варианты с одним значением

Comment: `insert into tableName (fieldName) values (1), (2), (3), .... (N)`

Comment: ну или insert into tableName (fieldName) SELECT field FROM field_table?

Comment: если из другой таблицы, то да

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE condition;
```